# Algorithm to determine clusters of linked nodes in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Say I have a dataset of 9 unique that are connected in the following way like this:

```
start  end
----------
    1    2
    2    3
    4    5
    6    7
    7    8
    7    1
    4    9
    9    5
```

The dataset represents a graph of nodes, and the links between them. So for instance, the given links are represented as two clusters: one with 6 nodes, and one with 3 nodes.

```
CLUSTER 1        CLUSTER 2

1 --- 2 --- 3    4 --- 5
|                 \___ |
|                     \|
7 --- 6                9
|
|
8
```

I want an efficient algorithm clusters the edges together like so:

```
node  cluster
-------------
   1        1
   2        1
   3        1
   4        2
   5        2
   6        1
   7        1
   8        1
   9        2
```

The problem is that I have a lot of these edges, and my current algorithm is pretty slow. Assuming that these datasets are represented as DataFrames in Spark, is there a more SQL-like way of achieving this besides stripping them down to RDDs and iterating over them like lists?

Comment: probably want to use [graphX](https://spark.apache.org/graphx/)

Answer (score 0):

Spark's GraphX library comes with a connected components method: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/graphx-programming-guide.html#connected-components

However I had tried using that in the past and found it a bit slow, so I ended up implementing it myself using the algorithm described here: http://mmds-data.org/presentations/2014/vassilvitskii_mmds14.pdf

It is very fast but requires a bit of implementation, probably beyond the scope of a stackoverflow answer (and the previous code I wrote is proprietary). And it's also possible GraphX has improved their implementation in the years since.